# Saving Pictures Only To Phone's External Storage

Tags: android, image, android-external-storage

I am making a small Camera App in which i am creating a folder in Phone External Storage, and all the pictures are saving in that folder
when there is no SD card in Phone, it creates the folder in phone external storage and the path is

```
D/Directory: .cameraApp/
```

and when there is SD card in Phone it creates the Folder on SD card and the path is

```
D/Directory:storage/sdcard0
```

How can i always save pictures on Phone External Storage, not in SD card.

How can we remove the sdcard from Path??
Thankyou

Comment: Phone External Storage and  SD card are same

Comment: On which external storage do you want to save it (physically), If there is no SdCard present?

Comment: @RafaelT i want to save pics in my own App, i don't want to show them in Gallery.. But when there is SD card in phones, it will save pictures in SD card storage and they are showing in Gallery

Comment: If the only problem is that it is in the Gallery, create a folder and put an empty file named `.nomedia` inside it. this will prevent the gallery from scanning it